# Regular expression to test the mathematical expression

Tags: regex

I dealing with regular expressions, this question arose. How to write a regular expression for math expression tests. I mean expression like this:

```
1+1
(1+1) * 2 / (4+1) + 3
```

and somthing like that.

I trying somthing like this:

```
"^(?:\\d+([*+-]|/(?!0)))+\\d+$"
```

But so does not pass option with brackets. How to make a regular expression that skipped both options that I described above? I need a regular expression to skip numbers, parentheses and fundamentals mathematical operations + - * / and spaces

Comment: Can the input contain nested brackets? If so general regular expressions aren't a powerful enough tool (although some advanced flavours such as perl's can handle it with recursive patterns)

Comment: Only one level of nesting

Comment: Looks like you're trying to avoid division by zero, is it an important part? I ask in part because you don't mention it in the question, but mostly because it would be awful to handle with regex as you'd have to represent every expression which evaluates to 0, that is `0`, `(\d)-\1`, `\d*0`, `0*\d`, `0+0`

Comment: No, I just need to check that a mathematical expression comes in which can have brackets with one level of nesting, and not a string with letters and any other characters.

Comment: I asked because the regex you posted tries to avoid division by 0 by handling the `/` operator separately and checking that it isn't followed by a 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following :

```
^(?:\d+|\(\d+\s*[-+/*]\s*\d+\))(?:\s*[-+/*]\s*(?:\d+|\(\d+\s*[-+/*]\s*\d+\)))*$
```

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/OsMO4k/2)

`(?:\d+|\(\d+\s*[-+/*]\s*\d+\))` is a single number or a bracketed operation. This is matched at least once, then is followed by as many occurences separated by an operator as necessary.